# Is there a way to track engagement time for custom events in Firebase Analytics for Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-analytics

We can log a custom event in Firebase Analytics for Flutter like so:

```
final analyticsObserver =
    Provider.of<FirebaseAnalyticsObserver>(context,
        listen: false);

analyticsObserver.analytics
    .logEvent(name: 'video_screen', 
        parameters: {
                'user_id': userProfile.userId,
                'screen': 'video_screen',
                'action': 'play',
                'type': 'meme',
                'highlight_id': 'DS7m4rEnxSiTe',
    });
```

The default Firebase events contain engagement time while there is none for custom event. Is there any way to include the engagement time in custom events?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Analytics measure screen time. So, along with logEvent you can also use setCurrentScreen and it generates screen time and it can serve the purpose.

```
 final FirebaseAnalytics _analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();

 Future logTime({@required String name}) async {
    await _analytics.setCurrentScreen(screenName: name);
  }
```

You can call this logTime function before any event and can measure the time in Analytics.

```
 locator<AnalyticsService>().logTime(name: "Dashboard");
```

You can see the report in Dashboard after 24 hrs.

[image: You can see the report in Dashboard after 24 hrs]

Comment: There is no screen time recorded in Firebase Analytics

Comment: Did you check it on DebugView?

Comment: The one that you are mentioning in your answer is by using screen not custom event.

Comment: Yes I have mentioned this. But it serves the purpose. Add whenever you want to log an event.

Comment: Yes, but the method that you are using does not differentiate each screen, for example, Article with content A and Article with content B. Hence, the need for me to add the id in the parameters for logEvent